# Using implode to generate csv file from mysql_query on joined tables, output gives fields duplicated?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT n.sbjnum, n.scan_no, d.name, d.tel_c, d.srvyr
                       FROM no_scans AS n 
                   JOIN details AS d ON n.sbjnum = d.sbjnum ");             
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $string1 = implode(" , ",$row) . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array of the column data in both associative and numerically indexed form.  You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

You might want to try using [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Around here we say thank you by accepting answers. Just look for the tick icon to the left of an answer that you want to accept.